# How to set the height equal to its width?

Tags: android, kotlin, tablelayout

I would like to make a board game like chess (8x8 cell board).
As the goal, I hope my application runs on several smartphones like screen dots (= 720px X 1280px, 1024px X 1920px, 1024 X 2340px).

The attached photo is my game board, and make the height equal to its width by input px value. In this result, 1024px X 1920px and 1024 X 2340px are OK.

Of cource, not for 720px X 1280px smartphones.

Could you give me your technics to control TableLayout's height equal to its width ?

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout"
    android:layout_width="1080px"
    android:layout_height="1080px"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGFY6.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed number of boxes/grids, I would recommend using `GridLayout` or `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`. Following is an example of `GridLayout` for a 2 X 2 case:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2">                    //specify number of column each row

    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"         //【important!! Not "layout_rowWeight"!!】
        android:gravity="center"                //center content
        android:text="Sam"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sam"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sam"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sam"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</GridLayout>
```

However, you will notice that its height is not equal to the width, that's because we use `match_parent` for the `GridLayout` to take the full width of the screen, but we use `wrap_content` for its height. So, set `match_parent` to the height? No good. Use hard code `dp`? No good. Well, turns out that there is an amazing attribute called `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` for the `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"                 //must be 0dp for either width or height
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"   //make the ratio 1:1
        android:columnCount="2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        ...

    </GridLayout>       

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

There you go.

Comment: I succeeded.
Thanks to you.
Whether the width is 720px or 1080px, I was able to get it to fill the entire screen.

android:layout_rowWeight="1" and
android:layout_columnWeight="1" were both required.
Maybe it's because I'm using both TextView and ImageView, total 100 over.

I'm really glad I asked this question to stack overflow.

I'll be releasing a chess-like game called "Fire Water Tree Land" on Google Play in the near future.　If you see it, I'd be happy if you could play it.

Thanks to your help, I have made great progress.

Surlofia